# Jest mocks of axios interceptors in Typescript failing

Tags: typescript, axios, jestjs

I am trying to mock axios interceptors using Jest in Typescript.  However, when running I get the error:
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'request' of undefined" on the following line:

```
axios.interceptors.request.use(async (config: AxiosRequestConfig) => {
```

Here is how I have defined the mock

```
jest.mock('axios', () => ({
  create: jest.fn(() => ({
    get: jest.fn(),
    interceptors: {
      request: {
        use: jest.fn((handler) => { interceptorFunction = handler; }),
      },
      response: {
        use: jest.fn((handler) => { interceptorFunction = handler; }),
      },
    },
  })),
}));
```

Any assistance/insights would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access to interceptors attribute of axios, but it is defined under the return value of create method. Thus, if you check the value of axios.interceptors via console.log function, the output must be 'undefined' and you can't access to any attribute of 'undefined'.
So, you have to change

```
axios.interceptors.request.use(...)
```

into

```
axios.create().interceptors.request.use(...)
```

or change the mock implementation like this.

```
jest.mock('axios', () => ({
  create: jest.fn(() => ({})),
  get: jest.fn(),
  interceptors: {
    request: {
      use: jest.fn((handler) => { //sth
      }),
    },
    response: {
      use: jest.fn((handler) => { //sth
      }),
    },
  },
}));
```